# Проблема с добавлением записи

Tags: wordpress

Добрый день, подскажите в чем может быть проблема, не могу добавить новую запись или страницу.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Посмотрел в БД, там нету доступа к редактированию определенных таблиц:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это может быть из-за этого? И куда обращаться по этому поводу, к хосту?

Comment: Какой-то плагин вам ломает все. Отключайте по одному плагины, начиная с установленного последним по времени и проверяйте как ведет себя страница редактирования поста.

Comment: пробовал все отключать, не получается.

Comment: Смотрите в панели хостинга права пользователя на базу какие.

Comment: Плохо пробовал. Отключай все плаги чисти все следы кешей, переключайся на дефолтную тему. ЗЫ. Ну и хлама в базе...

Answer (score -1):

Одна из причин отсутствия возможности редактирования может быть - отсутствие ключевого поля. Вернее, само поле есть, но оно потеряло свойство быть ключевым. Такое может произойти если базу импортировали из другого источника. Так часто бывает, когда переносили базу от одного провайдера к другому. Данные и структура переносятся, а вот ключевые поля и зависимости теряются. Исправлять приходится руками по каждой таблице.